# How to filter price using price slider

Tags: reactjs

I am having products array as below , from where I want to filter products  based on prices
 Now I want to filter products based on price
So I am using react-range package for price filtering 
My code is as below, but I am getting error  , could some one help me

items: [
            {
              _id: "1",
              name: "product1",
              desc:"Learn Python",
              image:"/images/pic1.jpg",
              price: 15,

```
        },
       {
          _id: "2",
          name: "product2",
          desc:"ReactJS from scrach",
         image:"/images/pic2.jpg",
          price: 12

        },
        {
          _id: "3",
          name: "product3",
          desc:"Learn Javascript ",
         image:"/images/pic3.jpg",
          price: 65,

        },
       {
          _id: "4",
          name: "product4",
         desc:"Learn Vue js ",
         image:"/images/pic4.jpg",
          price: 50,

        }

      ]
    };



const MIN = 0;
const MAX = 100;
const [min, setMin] = useState(MIN);
const [max, setMax] = useState(MAX);
const [priceFilter, setPriceFilter] = useState([min, max]);

 setMin( items.reduce((m, p) => (p.price < m ? p.price : m), Infinity));
 setMax(items.reduce((m, p) => (p.price > m ? p.price : m), -Infinity));

    return(
            <>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div className="filter">
                {items.length && (
                  <Range
                    step={10}
                    min={min}
                    max={max}
                    values={priceFilter}
                    onChange={(values) => setPriceFilter(values)}
                    renderTrack={({ props, children }) => (
                      <div
                        onMouseDown={props.onMouseDown}
                        onTouchStart={props.onTouchStart}
                        style={{
                          ...props.style,
                          height: "36px",
                          display: "flex",
                          width: "100%",
                        }}
                      >
                        <div
                          ref={props.ref}
                          style={{
                            height: "5px",
                            width: "100%",
                            borderRadius: "4px",
                            background: getTrackBackground({
                              values: priceFilter,
                              colors: ["#ccc", "#548BF4", "#ccc"],
                              min,
                              max,
                            }),
                            alignSelf: "center",
                          }}
                        >
                          {children}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    )}
                    renderThumb={({ props, isDragged }) => (
                      <div
                        {...props}
                        style={{
                          ...props.style,
                          height: "16px",
                          width: "16px",
                          borderRadius: "1px",
                          backgroundColor: "#FFF",
                          display: "flex",
                          justifyContent: "center",
                          alignItems: "center",
                          boxShadow: "0px 1px 2px #888888",
                        }}
                      >
                        <div
                          style={{
                            height: "8px",
                            width: "3px",
                            backgroundColor: isDragged ? "#548BF4" : "#CCC",
                          }}
                        />
                      </div>
                    )}
                  />
                )}
                <div className="form-row price-range">
                  <div>{priceFilter[0]}</div>
                  <div>{priceFilter[1]}</div>
                </div>
                <button className="button primary">Apply</button>
              </div>
            </li>
         </ul>

            {items.map(item=>(
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src={item.image} alt={item.name}>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{item.name}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{item.desc}</p>
        <p class="price">${item.price}</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    ))}
        </>   
        )
```

Comment: can you provide error?

Comment: if you want to set min and max for the slider you can filter prices from products array and get min and max of that array by just using Math.min(array) and Math.max(array)

Comment: You are right but I have to filter price from a json array , therefore I think I need to apply reduce method ,when I am going to render reduce method it throws an error.If you have any different method or other opinion please help me.

Answer (score 0):

@ a_m_dev , Thanks for your reply

I am attaching errors as follows 
error1- This error pops up when these setMin,SetMax are outside of the useEffect
 https://pasteboard.co/Jaavppm.png

```
setMin( items.reduce((m, p) => (p.price < m ? p.price : m), Infinity));
 setMax(items.reduce((m, p) => (p.price > m ? p.price : m), -Infinity));
```

error2: This error pops up when these setMin,SetMax are inside the useEffect

https://pasteboard.co/JaavYPC.png